# Mongoose Validate Foreign Key (ref)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried several different ways to validate a foreign key in Mongoose and cannot figure it out.

I have a schema like this:

```
//Doctors.js
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String }
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('Doctors', schema);

//Patients.js
var Doctors = require('./Doctors');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String },
  doctor: { type: String, ref: 'Doctors' }
}
schema.pre('save', function (next, req) {
  Doctors.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function (err, found) {
    if (found) return next();
    else return next(new Error({error:"not found"}));
  });
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Patients', schema);
```

however I get an this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findOne'`

Anyone know how to do something similar to what I am trying to do here?

Comment: So, I'm able to get it working on my machine using mongoose 4.0.5 and mongo 2.4.6.  What do you get when you `console.log(Doctors)`?

Comment: I get `{}`. But I just found the answer, give me a second to post it

Answer (score 3):

I kept googling over the past hour, and saw something about scope that got me thinking. The following code fixed my problem.

```
//Doctors.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String }
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('Doctors', schema);

//Patients.js
//var Doctors = require('./Doctors'); --> delete this line
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String },
  doctor: { type: String, ref: 'Doctors' }
}
schema.pre('save', function (next, req) {
  var Doctors = mongoose.model('Doctors'); //--> add this line
  Doctors.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function (err, found) {
    if (found) return next();
    else return next(new Error({error:"not found"}));
  });
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Patients', schema);
```

Although this was a quick fix, in no way was it an obvious fix (at least to me). The issue was the scope of variables.

Comment: Hi jeremy i have a query regarding how you have assigned your foreign key  so can we refer any key i meant as far i as i have seen most peoples use {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"some collection"} will your method work finely?

Comment: @Jeremy it's really unclear where you think req comes from this is a mongoose callback and not an express one